# How to run specific exe file from .msi instaler

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer

I've created .msi file for a project (App.prj) with Visual Studio Installer, but in order to run installed App.exe, I have to install one more Dependent.exe file which is required to run App.exe.
How to run Dependent.exe within App.msi?

Answer (score 2):

Custom Actions

http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/custom-actions.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335516/Custom-Action-in-Visual-Studio-setup-projects